# Interpreting regression output with categorical IV and log-transformed DV

Tags: regression, categorical-data, data-transformation, logarithm

I'm trying to make sense of some results I ran on a weighted regression with log-transformed IV1 and DV, and IV2, which is a factor variable. IV2 is *restaurant price range*, categorized as 1 (low price range) or 4 (high price range), to be exact.

I'm trying to interpret the effect of IV2 on the DV. The coefficient for the price range is 0.657:

log(*DV*) = 2.99 + 0.657(*price4*) + 1.11(*log_IV1*) - 0.190(*log_IV1* * *price4*)

This seems to mean that with a higher price range of 4, the DV will increase (exp(0.657)-1)*100%. Is this correct? I'm feeling confused because when I run a regression where IV1 and DV are NOT log-transformed, results will say that the DV will decrease with a higher price range of 4:

*DV* = 306.87 - 47.44(*price4*) + 576.77(*IV1*) - 175.67(*IV1* * *price4*)

How can I explain this difference in results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you also are including an interaction term, and this makes an interpretation of the "main" effect of price4 challenging.  The reason is that this is a partial slope (in both models).  That is to say, this is the rate of change in the dependent variable with one unit change in this independent variable ASSUMING all other variables are held constant.  And here's the rub, you can't hold the interaction constant while changing the main variable of focus.

My expectation would be that if you plugged in corresponding values for IV1 and log_IV1 and simplified each model, then the signs for your "slope" for price4 would be the same.

Happy to clarify/elaborate more if desired.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand what you're explaining. For example, if I were to plug in 20 for IV1 and log(20) for log_IV1, the coefficients would be the same. Do you think it is still 'correct' to say that there's a main effect of price range where price range 4 will result in greater DV than price range 1? It's just that when I write this in a report, it intuitively makes sense to have a negative coefficient with price4, just as in the analysis with regular IV1...

Comment: Because your model includes the additional variables, one effective strategy to convey the rate of change for a specific variable is to pick representative variables for the other independent variables (say a low and high value or low/medium/high).  Then you can calculate the equation with just price4.  You can then report the nature of change for each of these special cases.  So it would be repeating the idea 2 or 3 times, but allowing for you to "control" for the effect of the other variables.